# Comparing arrays from Mongoose using ShouldJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, should.js

Taking an array such as ['hello', 'there'] and storing that in a Mongoose document with a schema such as

```
tags: { type: Array }
```

using something such as:

```
Something.create({ tags: ['hello', 'there']}, cb);
```

Then using ShouldJS to check that the document matches my supplied array I would expect this:

```
doc.tags.should.eql(['hello', 'there']);
```

But it does not. If I console.log doc tags I get:

```
[hello, there]
```

Notice that the quotes are gone. The doc.tags is indeed an array (I can check instanceof Array) and I can also use shouldjs with

```
doc.tags.should.have.keys('hello');
doc.tags.should.have.keys('there');
```

Anyone have an idea as to why my array doesn't match anymore?

Comment: Silly question and could be a type, but when you output do you get [hello, there] or ['hello', 'there'] as they wouldn't be equal

Comment: Did you ever get an answe to this problem? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @dworrad - nope, never figured that one out.

Answer (score 3):

Your array is not a real json `Array`: it's a `MongooseArray`, with additional methods.

To make `should.eql` work with mongoose array, first use `toObject()`:

```
doc.tags.toObject().should.eql(['hello', 'there']);
```